# C restore stdout to terminal

Tags: c, stdout

I am working with a multi-thread program.

First I redirect my stdout to a certain file. No problem there (I used `dup2(fd, 1)` where `fd` is the file descriptor for the file).

Afterwards, I need to redirect my stdout to the terminal again.

My first approach:

```
      /*Declaration*/
      fpost_t  stream_sdout;
      /*code*/
      if ( fgetpos( stdout, &stream_sdout) == -1 )
          perror(Error:);
```

It says illegal seek.
No idea why this is happening.
But if I get this to work, then I only need to use `fsetpos(stdout, &stream_stdout)` and it should work.

My second idea, was to to copy the stdout using `dup2(stdout, 4)` to the file descriptor table, at position 4. But that ain't working either.

How can I switch the standard output back to its original destination (terminal, pipe, file, whatever)?

Comment: I have a feeling that trying to move `stdout` around like this is probably a bad idea -- what position exactly should the _terminal_ report in `fgetpos()`? Why not simply open a file and output to it using `fwrite()` or `fprintf()` or `write()` and output to the terminal via `/dev/tty` when you need it?

Comment: @sarnold:  probably because the program has libraries or other unalterable code which are hardwired to `stdout`.

Comment: @sarnold i actually didnt give it thought to that posibility. Let me check quickly.

Comment: I don't have enough information to post a good answer, so I'm commenting instead. In Windows, you can re-attach the console. I'd look at any Win32 SDK documentation. It's not hard; I just can't remember how to do it.

Comment: @sarnold thanks for the advice! That was much easier. I was able to make it work to perfection.
I still have the doubt if restoring the std is possible, but your solution got me out of a tight spot. Thanks!

Comment: @Alessandroempire: [wallyk's answer covers _restoring the stdout_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11042281/377270) very nicely. :)

Comment: Before tweaking it you could first save the original stdout fd by a dup2() (use fileno) and save the dupped fd for later. Dont forget to flush.

Comment: You can't seek on a terminal (or on a pipe).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>

...

int saved_stdout;

...

/* Save current stdout for use later */
saved_stdout = dup(1);
dup2(my_temporary_stdout_fd, 1);

... do some work on your new stdout ...

/* Restore stdout */
dup2(saved_stdout, 1);
close(saved_stdout);
```

Comment: This really helped me out a lot. I was wondering though what is the function of close(saved_stdout)? I've used close for closing files but I am not yet familiar with how the whole dup function process works.

Comment: @ThinkBonobo, `saved_stdout` is a duplicate (hence, *dup()*) of the original file descriptor for the original file underlying the program's stdout.  When is it again duplicated back to (*dup2()*) stdout (file descriptor no. 1), the program has two copies/handles/descriptors for the same underlying file.  There's no need for this once the output redirection is finished (and it might confound resource limits or assumptions about file locks, etc.), so good practice is to dismiss the resource when no longer needed.

Answer (score 13):

Before you do the `dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO)`, you should save the current open file descriptor for standard output by doing `int saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);` (letting [`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) choose an available file descriptor number for you).  Then, after you've finished with the output redirected to a file, you can do `dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO)` to restore standard output to where it was before you started all this (and you should close `saved_stdout` too).

You do need to worry about flushing standard I/O streams (`fflush(stdout)`) at appropriate times as you mess around with this.  That means 'before you switch stdout over'.

Answer (score 0):

If the program runs on a Linux environment, you can `freopen ("/dev/stdout", "a", stdout)`.

But if you know that `stdout` was the terminal, `freopen ("/dev/tty", "a", stdout)` or the equivalent for other OSs—even Windows.

Comment: When the `dup2()` works, `/dev/stdout` should refer to the file.  So you've switched the output from the file to the file, I believe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  If he is changing the `fd`s around, that would be true.  It is far from apparent from his description that is what is happening.  It seems he might be changing around the FILE connections instead.

Comment: Since he mentions using `dup2()` to switch the standard output, it seems to me he is messing with file descriptors to start with.  The code to reset things in the question is weird beyond rescue; a rewrite is in order.  But that's what the answers are supposed to be about, of course.