# C directing stdout to file and then resetting

Tags: c, stdout, file-descriptor, execvp, output-redirect

I would like to change the file descriptor so that my `execvp` commands are sent to a file. Afterwards, I would like to reset `stdout` back to the console.

This is what I have so far:

```
int main() {
    printf("to console\n");
    int stdoutfd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    FILE* file = fopen("./test.txt","ab+");
    int filefd = fileno(file);
    dup2(filefd,STDOUT_FILENO);
    char *args[] = {"ls","-la",NULL};
    execvp(args[0],args);
    dup2(stdoutfd,STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(stdoutfd);
    printf("to console\n");
}
```

The first `printf` prints to console, then the execvp on the "ls -la" commands gets printed to the `test.txt` file, but my problem is that the second `printf` does not print anywhere.

I realize a similar question has been answered at
[C restore stdout to terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042218/c-restore-stdout-to-terminal), but that solution does not seem to work.

Comment: `execvp` does not return on success. `execvp` "replaces the current process image with a new process image". That is, unless there is an error with the `execvp` call, none of the code after the `execvp` will ever execute. You probably want to `fork` first before calling `execvp`.

Comment: Have you worked out why that other answer doesn't work?  It gives solid advice (and mine isn't the accepted answer).  It will work if your program is sane — the example in the question has no `fork()` so there is nothing executed after a successful `execvp()`.  The last three lines are never executed if the `execvp()` works.  You could change the `"ls"` string into `"not-the-ls"` (assuming you don't have a command called `not-the-ls`, of course) and rerun; then you'd see the `to console` message.

Comment: Correct; the only time any of the `exec*()` family of function returns is when it has failed to execute whatever it was asked to execute.

Answer (score 2):

There is no afterwards. The `execvp` function call replaces your process. If it succeeds, the rest of your code does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

regarding re-assigning stdout to go to a different location

This is from:
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c`

Why use freopen()? The C89 specification has the answer in one of the endnotes for the section on :

```
116. The primary use of the freopen function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout), as those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value returned by the fopen function may be assigned.
```

freopen is commonly misused, e.g. stdin = freopen("newin", "r", stdin);. This is no more portable than fclose(stdin); stdin = fopen("newin", "r");. Both expressions attempt to assign to stdin, which is not guaranteed to be assignable.

The right way to use freopen is to omit the assignment: freopen("newin", "r", stdin);