# Switching cout back to writing to the screen

Tags: c++, cout

In my program I am switching my cout to write to a file using the following:

```cpp
int newstdout = open("myFile.txt",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);    
close(1);    
dup(newstdout);    
close(newstdout);
```

How would I later in the program switch back to my cout printing to the screen(terminal)?

Comment: Does that code do what you claim it does?

Comment: You closed fd 1 (stdout), you're SOL. See here for possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042218/c-restore-stdout-to-terminal

Answer (score 3):

The *correct* way to make `cout` (or any other stream) output to a different target is to call its [`rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) method to swap in a different stream buffer. You can then swap back in the old buffer later, if needed. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream outfile("myFile.txt");
auto cout_buff = std::cout.rdbuf();

std::cout.rdbuf(outfile.rdbuf());
// anything written to std::cout will now go to myFile.txt instead...

std::cout.rdbuf(cout_buff);
// anything written to std::cout will now go to STDOUT again...
```